# Python file to read in binary and write in xml

Tags: python, xml, binary

I have a binary file which was created by a VBA file (I don't work with VBA or binary at all) but I need to get Python to read this binary file (which includes a list of inputs for a calculation) and then write these values into an xml file.

If I know the order of the inputs into the file that is created, is it possible to read the binary code line by line, to get input by input and then write into the xml?

I have to use Python rather than VBA since I am not authorised to change the original VBA files.

I apologise for the lack of information, I only know a bit of Python and have never worked with VBA or binary. I really appreciate any help anyone can give me! Thank you =)

Comment: You don't seem to know the format of your file.  Without this information, there's nothing you can do with the data.

Comment: It's a binary file which in the end I want to have in the format of an xml file.

Comment: binary is not a format. If you want to read the vba file you need to find out what the format looks like.

Comment: How do I find out what the format looks like please?

Comment: Is the file just pure data, one number after another, or is it format more complicated than that? Do you know what the first few numbers should be?

Comment: When you say "order of the inputs" -- do you also know the data types, endianness / byte ordering, &c.? One quick general answer: Use the `ctypes` module to parse the data, and `ElementTree` to build your new structure for output (if the files aren't large enough that you'd need a streaming API -- etree, being DOM-style, needs to build everything in memory). How, exactly, to use ctypes depends on information you apparently don't have.

Comment: When I look it up in notepad its more complicated but I can see that the first two numbers are 1 and 623 but after that it changes completely. I should be able to know the order of the inputs and I will know all of them as I input them myself.

Comment: @user982297 - Run `hexdump -C -n 32 your_filename` and copy the output here. This will give us an idea how the binary file (at least its beginning) looks like.

Comment: If you have the VBA code that produced the file, then read the documentation for the functions it calls. They should give your the information. If not, you can try opening the file in a hex editor. That'll give you the raw binary data and you can hopefully figure out what's going on.

Comment: Where do I run that, in command prompt? Sorry, I feel don't do much programming but I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I think that we'll need to add a test people will have to pass in order to be able to post on SO, this is a site for programmers only and I doubt that someone will be able to teach you basic computer concepts like binary and command line. If you do not know these you shouldn't try to code anything.

Comment: @sorin - probably not a test, just vote to close on questions that have nearly no hope of being answered (I'll start)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the VBA code that made the file you should be able to copy the data structure in python and then deserialize it.

Comment: This sounds interesting, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look through that =)

Answer (score 0):

Python is probably not the best tool, I would recommend VBA as it is going to be best suited to reading that file.  Then, create your xml file as output.